# Django 1.6 How to change a list to queryset or How to write this kind of query?

Tags: django

I want to get all the questinos with no answers.I use this:

```
all_questions=[q for q in Question.objects.all() if not q.answer_set.all()]
```

It works. But then I need to invoke `order_by` method with all_questions, so I need to change it to a queryset, how?

Or, is there a standard method like `Question.objects.filter(answer_count=0)` ? I find hard but no results.

Solution: **Change answer_count__gt=0 to answer_count=0.**

```
   all_questions=Question.objects.annotate(answer_count=Count('answer')).filter(answer_count=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an annotation much more efficiently than doing one query per question.

```
Question.objects.annotate(answer_count=Count('answer')).filter(answer_count=0)
```

That said, you could just add the order_by directly into your Questions.objects.all() query. But like I said, it's much less efficient to do a query per question.

Comment: Just curious,is it possible to  change a list to a queryset?

Comment: Oh,I just use your method, but no effects, it returns all questions include the one with answers

Comment: Hey, I misread your intent. Yes, that's correct, you filter by that property as usual. No you can't change a list to a queryset, unless you run another query, like `Question.objects.filter(id__in=[getattr(x, id) for x in my_list_of_objects])`